# NSPredicate - Core Data - Compare two properties to each other

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nspredicate

I have what I thought would be an easy thing to do / find on the Google-verse but have been totally baffled.  I have a single object with two date properties setup in Core Data.  I want to grab a list of objects where the two dates are not the same.  How can I do this using Core Data?

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateModified != dateCreated"];
```

does not work.

Comment: That should work just fine.  In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to compare 2 properties?

Answer (score 1):

The format you are using is searching for a key-value relation, but you have keys on both sides, `dateModified` and `dateCreated`. Try something like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dateModified != %@)", someObject.dateCreated]
```